# How do I set up command blocks to teleport the winning team?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Summary: I am making a mini game in Minecraft where you kill the other teams which you can select from either a wolf or ocelot (it's already tamed).

Question: How can I set it up to teleport all the players and say the team that won.

What I tried: I tried using `/scoreboard objectives add leader_stat stat.killEntity.Ozelot`. Then in another command block I typed `/testfor @a[score=leader_stat=1]` so when 1 kill happens it will activate but I can't add the two teams, then I get all lost.

Comment: You spelled ocelot wrong.

Comment: @caleb its spelled ozelot in the commands

Comment: Oh really? I learn something everyday!

Comment: @caleb I use /summon ozelot to summon them

Comment: The question is somewhat vague. Obviously these aren't Vanilla commands. So which server / plugins are you using? Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Scoreboard is a Vanilla command.

Answer (score 1):

The command to check if anyone on team `red` has killed an ocelot is

```
/testfor @a[score_leader_stat=1, team=red]
```

Note that there's an underscore between `score` and `leader_stat`, not an equal sign!
Get the output of that command block and hook it into two other command blocks with

```
/tp @a[team=red] x y z
/tellraw @a {text:"Red Team has slain the Ocelot!", color:red}
```

In a 1.8 snapshot, you could also use

```
/title @a title {text:"Red Team has slain the Ocelot!", color:red}
```

to get a large text display. 
You will need a set of such command blocks for every team and every possible leader. Note that if red team's leader is an Ocelot as well, they will also win the game by killing their own leader.

Comment: Can you help with my new scoreboard question